# a problem while trying to install

Tags: software-installation

when i trying to install any program in terminal i found the same problem like this.
and if i try to install it from ubuntu software it not able to start

and this what i found on the terminal:

```
mz@mz-32:~$ sudo apt-get -f install lmms
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-83-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-83-generic but it is not going to be installed
 lmms : Depends: lmms-common (>= 1.1.3-1build1) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libstk-4.5.0 but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: stk but it is not going to be installed
        Recommends: tap-plugins but it is not going to be installed
        Recommends: caps but it is not going to be installed
N: Ignoring file '50unattended-upgrades.ucf-old' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: try to run only this `sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: OK I will make it as an answer, please vote and accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get a message `E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).`

Run only this command

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```